# Mongo map reduce and sort

Tags: php, mongodb

```
collection: users
fields: name, age
```

I wish to apply a map reduce function in PHP that will return the count for users, grouped by age and sorted by age.

I can't find any good examples in PHP using the native php-mongo driver to do this. Of course I don't want to sort on client side because the results might be huge.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002841/mongo-map-reduce-first-time) is good example how to run m/r from php.

Comment: @Andrew there is no sort

Comment: You can output the results of map reduce to a new collection, and subsequently sort this collection.  If you're doing inline map reduce, there is no way to sort the results.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you have your connection, and collection grabbing sorted already. You will have to use the [MongoCollection::group()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.group.php) function to get the result

```
$keys    = array('age' => 1);
$initial = array('count' => 0);
$reduce  = "function(doc, out) { out.count++; }";

$result = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);

var_dump($result)
```

As for the sort: MongoDB doesn't support sorting the result of a group, you'll have to do in php. This is because group() returns a single document and not a cursor, and it cannot be sorted before it's returned. As per documentation:

*"To order the grouped data, simply sort it client-side upon return."*

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support sorting the result of a group, you'll have to do in php. This is because group() returns a single document and not a cursor, and it cannot be sorted before it's returned.

Comment: in mongo docs: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce, <sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces>]